# how to configure chromium driver & set browser window size/viewport size in webdriverio config file

Tags: webdriver-io

I want to set up the chromium driver & set up capability to open in particular viewport width X height in my config file used with webdriverio tool. I want the capability option for chromium, so that test will start with that configuration.

I have tried the following, but not working fine

I am using webdriverIO v5

Comment: what did you try? could you add your config file? I understand that you are trying to launch chrome in a particular height and width

Comment: @Raju, I am trying to launch 'Edge chromium' (not Chrome) browser with '1200X700' window dimension

Answer (score 1):

```
browser.setWindowSize(1800, 2000); // <-- this command
```

Check [documentation](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/setWindowSize.html)

And you can add it into wdio.conf.js if you want to do it before tests

```
  /**
   * Gets executed before test execution begins. At this point you can access to all global
   * variables like `browser`. It is the perfect place to define custom commands.
   * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
   * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that are to be run
   */
  // before: function (capabilities, specs) {
  // },
```

Comment: It works perfect. This should be marked as a solution to the problem